# Importance of caching vs. modularizing .LESS

Tags: optimization, less, browser-cache

Hopefully this isn't two general of a question. I have a *very* large .LESS codebase and I'm trying to find the best way to optimize it page speed, maintainability, and overall "best practice".

Say I have many different page types, Homepage, About Page, Articles, Support Page, Product Page, etc. And many more .LESS modules for say sliders, carousels, modals, videos, articles, prodPage, support, about, homepage, footer, header, etc.

## We can import it a few different ways:

**1) Same for every page:** I import *everything* on first page load, it's large slowing down page load and every page doesn't need all the styles, but on subsequent pages it should be cached and won't have to load anything

*styles.less:*

```
@import homepage;
@import prodPage;
@import about;
@import articles;
@import modals;
@import carousels;
@import videos;
@import ...
```

**2) Same for every page type:** I import all the little modules (which there is a lot of) in one file as they're more likely to be reused elsewhere, and then separate out the page type specific stuff. This way within the page type everything will be cached. When the user goes to another page type they will still have to load the styles for the new page type but they'll already have all the modules cached. But each page is unlikely to need all the mixins (not all pages will have videos, or carousels, etc:

*homepage.less:*

```
@import homepage;
@import ...
```

*mixins.less*

```
@import modals;
@import carousels;
@import videos;
@import ...
```

**3) Different file for every page:** This way a .LESS file is customized for every page. This way no styles will go unused, only necessary files are downloaded. This will make pages very small (and therefore page load fast), but there will be little to no caching as every page will be different. Plus there is the obvious workload overhead of creating all of these as opposed to downloading it all at once:

*articleOne.less:*

```
@import articles;
@import videos;
```

*articleTwo.less*

```
@import articles;
@import carousels;
@import sliders;
```

So in the end, #1 is optimized for caching but leads to large stylesheet download and slower initial page load. #3 is optimized for small quick page loads but with no caching. #2 seems like a middleman.

Disregarding for now if this is over-optimization or not, what would be the best technique? What is the "standard practice"?